# Is my MagSafe covered under my MacBook's AppleCare?

Tags: power, applecare, magsafe

I have a white 2010 MacBook, and the outer casing for the wire on the MagSafe power adapter has developed a small split. Is this something that may be covered under my MacBook's AppleCare? Is it something that a genius might give me a "one time exception" for?

[image: Nicked power cable]

Comment: I suggest you go directly to Apple to ask about this. You'll get a more definitive answer from them.

Comment: oh it happened to me too, mine is worse, i don't understand why this should happen, my macbook 2012 was only 5 months old when this happened, i just used tape to cover it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Troubleshooting MagSafe adapters](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1713)

> **Whether your product is in or out of warranty**, you can take your adapter to an Apple Authorized Service Provider or Apple Retail Store for evaluation and replacement if necessary. **Pending the results of the evaluation, you may or may not be eligible for a replacement adapter free of charge.** Signs of accidental damage would negate any coverage. Be sure to bring in the computer used with the adapter; it is required to process potential adapter replacements.

So there are competing things at play. If your cable is otherwise pristine, no bends, no mars, no scuffs and it's clearly not worn - you might think that this split could be caused by either abuse/nick/cut/carelessness or perhaps not holding up as designed. If the rest of the adapter cord is worn and starting to show normal signs that it's just wearing out (no cord lasts forever, especially when wrapped, unwrapped, tugged) you might be asked to pay for a replacement if it's not clear the physical separation was a defect in manufacturing.

If Apple didn't make the cable correctly, it's likely it would fail immediately, but the longer the time that passes until you take it in for service, it's more likely to be an external force causing the tear. Usually by inspecting the rest of the cable (not pictured) you will see other signs of excessive force so absent those signs of stretching and tearing, this might be covered despite what looks like an obvious cut/rip due to a tug.

Comment: The Genius decided that my adapter is not covered, but another employee was helpful. Call it a one-time-exception. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Provided your Applecare is still valid, it can be used to claim on any faulty or damaged cable.

I took a cable I bought on Amazon back to them with my laptops Applecare number (and told them the truth about it - I didn't pretend it belonged with my Mac) and received a replacement free of charge.

It's definitely worth making an Genius bar appointment about it, provided you purchased the 3-year Applecare package - as a 2010 machine will be out of warrantee otherwise, and they may not cover the cable (although the others before me seem to think they will).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it finally came to a point where it tore on its own. It was just naturally stretching and breaking. This was happening without me even doing anything. I've had it for 11 months now. I've never had problems with laptop chargers; this is the first time.

I went to the Apple Store in Grand Central Station in New York City. The guy who was doing the appointments for the Genius Bar workers said that they wouldn't cover it so don't even bother wasting your time, but when I went to another Apple Store in New Jersey — they covered it with no questions asked.

Comment: @user63884 You seem to have created a second account to [add detail](http://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/46840) to a question posted to your first account! [Please merge your accounts!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Answer (score -1):

AppleCare does cover your MagSafe adapter and Apple also replaces any cables that are dangerous so if you take it down to your Apple Store then they will replace it for you.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem except there are other signs of bulging along the cable.  The computer is less than a month old and treated like a goddess with care.  I went back to the Apple store and was accused that I damaged it.  There are no scuffs, crushes, or any sign of physical interference. This looks to me as a manufacturing fault of both the cable sheath being weak and the outer shield being wound with uneven tension.  Apple needs to make good on this and have better customer response.  Needless to say, this is my last Mac.

Comment: So, was it covered under AppleCare or not?

Answer (score -2):

No they don't, they wouldn't replace mine and mine is dangerous